# Android: No resource found powered_by_google_light icon in build tools 23.0.3?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services, google-places-api, build-tools

I have always used the `powered_by_google` icons as I'm using the `Google Places API`. They look like this:

[image]

On this site, it says the icons are included within the Google Play services library: https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/attributions

> The 'Powered by Google' image is included in the Google Play services
>   library, in the correct sizes for Android apps. You may not resize or
>   modify these images in any way:
>
> For use on a light background: @drawable/powered_by_google_light For
>   use on a dark background: @drawable/powered_by_google_dark

Now, previously, I would just reference the icons in my xml by doing this:

```
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/powered_by_google_inner"
                android:src="@drawable/powered_by_google_light"
                android:padding="8dp"/>
```

Now after upgrading my Google Play Services library from 8.4 to 9.2.1, the drawable is no longer found in my libraries and I get this error when I try to build my app:

> Error:(14, 22) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src'
>   with value '@drawable/powered_by_google_light'). Error:Execution
>   failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>
> > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
> >     '/Users/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/23.0.3/aapt'' finished with
> >     non-zero exit value 1

This is my app.gradle (an extract):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.2.1') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.2.1') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.2.1') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.2.1') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:9.2.1') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.2.1') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

This is my main gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

For now, I'm using a workaround in that I'm downloading the icons from here: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/policies and incorporating them into my apps drawable folders.

Comment: Sounds like the documentation is out of date if an update doesn't have that resource

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some places functionality moved into its own library in v9.2. You need to add `com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.2.1` to your gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

It's freak, but in my case I had to un-install Google Repository and then re install Google Repository from Android SDK "Extras"  section.