# I can not import "com.google.android.gms.location.places.PlacePhotoMetadata"

Tags: android, api, android-studio, google-places-api

I'm developing a app in which I use the google map api and the place google api. But the problem is when I try to import the library "com.google.android.gms.location.places.PlacePhotoMetadata", this library not detected for the android studio. Any idea how it could do or a tutorial complete. Thank you.

Comment: Post error info or something to reproduce your problem

Comment: Post your `build.gradle` file.

Comment: what is the exact error message?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38427401/2994